How to click on a button if the button is found, but if not found, continue the test?
I have a test script that I need to automate: if a certain button is displayed on the page, then I need to click on it and continue with the next steps of the test. If the button is missing on the page, I also need to continue running the test.
All the solutions that I have found give an error when the button is not found, but I need this situation to be simply ignored
An example of something that is not suitable because it causes the test to fail:
dashboardPage.isVisible(showMoreReposButton, function(result) {
            if (result.value) {
                dashboardPage.click(showMoreReposButton);
            }
        });

if (dashboardPage.element(showMoreReposButton).isVisible()) {
            await dashboardPage.element(showMoreReposButton).click()
        }


Are you using Playwright or Nightwatch? Please tag appropriately. It looks like you're not awaiting these promises. Generally, ignoring/suppressing errors isn't a good thing. You should share the full error, because it's probably important to get to the root cause of your issue. A complete, runnable [mcve] and context for what you're trying to achieve would make it easier to help. Generally, it's not a good idea to introduce nondeterminism into tests (assuming you're testing, not scraping).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
